# Why are my special characters '>>' being replaced with diamonds with question marks?

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

here are the two lines of code in which I'm printing the special characters '>' and '>>'. however, they are being displayed as diamonds w question marks on the webpage.

```
paginationHtml = paginationHtml+\"<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='getCommentList(\"+next_page+\")'>Next› </a>&nbsp\";
paginationHtml = paginationHtml+\"<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='getCommentList(\"+page_count+\")'>Last» </a>&nbsp\";
```

Comment: What encoding/character set is the page being served with? And what encoding/character set was the above JavaScript saved as? If the two don't match, anything other than simple ASCII characters is going to be problematic.

Comment: If none of that makes sense, you might want to look through [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: e.g. [here](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/avQzmj), with saved/served charsets in sync, all is well. Nothing in your code itself shows us the actual problem.

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I have very similar code in a different file (they're bix files). And the special characters show up fine on the website. Just the special characters from this specific file (although almost the exact same code) show up as diamonds with question marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I needed to change the encoding of my file. In PHPStorm, go to 'File' then 'File Encoding'. For me, I needed to choose 'UTF-8' encoding. I converted the code and now the ">>" characters show up fine in the website!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `html` file is saved in the same format you declare in the `head` section. If for instance your file is `utf-8` encoded, put this in your `html`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

If you use `ansi` encoding, then

```
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-8">
</head>
```

... etc, but it should correspond. If you have the choice for your file encoding, go for `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

To display special characters like `›` & `»`, your simplest solution is to save and display all your documents in `UTF-8`.

**3 Steps:**

**1.** In your root .htaccess file, specify

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js
```

**2.** At the top of your .html document, just below `<head>`, add

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**3.** Importantly, *make sure* that you are saving any documents from your text editor with `UTF-8` encoding.